# Array to string conversion error with json_encode

Tags: php, mysql

I have a connect function for my MySQL database like so:

```
function connect() {

        $config = parse_ini_file('../../config.ini');

        // Try and connect to the database
        self::$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);

        //Check if both are bools and FALSE === checks type and equality
        if(self::$conn === false) {

            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            header("Content-Type: application/json");
            $response = array("Response"=>"Failed to connect to the database");
            echo "json_encode($response)";
            die();

        }


    }
```

I am having an issue when I do json_encode (for the fail connection). I get the error : ****Notice**:  Array to string conversion in **/var/www/html/somesite.co/public_html/API/index.php** on line **47**

json_encode(Array)**

Really have no idea why I'm getting this error. I have encoded and echo'd and array like this before with no issues. Could someone give me some pointers to what I might be doing wrong please?

Comment: `echo json_encode($response);`,  function should not be wrapped in quotes

Comment: echo json_encode($response); is enough, no need for ".

Comment: I thought with double quotes echo would still evaluate any functions inside?

Comment: I think only variable names are evaluated, not function calls.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error as you are trying to `echo` an `array`. And you don't wrap a function call in quotes.

replace

```
echo "json_encode($response)";
```

with

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: `dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>` still giving me same error